# Reduce xarray.Dataset by custom function

Tags: python, python-xarray

I want to use `xarray` functionality to reduce a dataset by a custom/external function across a named dimension.

Create dataset to demonstrate the problem

```py
import xarray as xr 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

time = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", "2001-01-01", freq="D")
sids = np.arange(4)
obs = np.random.random(size=(len(time), len(sids)))
sim = np.random.random(size=(len(time), len(sids)))

original = xr.Dataset({"obs": (("time", "station_id"), obs), "sim": (("time", "station_id"), sim)}, coords={"time": time, "station_id": sids})
```

I want to calculate the `mean_squared_error` using the two variables in original, calculating the metric by collapsing the `"time"` dimension. This should return an `xr.Dataset` like the following:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:             (station_id: 4)
Coordinates:
  * station_id          (station_id) int64 0 1 2 3
Data variables:
    mean_squared_error  (station_id) float64 0.4411 0.183 0.06754 0.9662
```

I have tried using the [`reduce`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.reduce.html) function

```py
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

original.reduce(mean_squared_error, dim="time")
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-243-51111f05437b> in <module>
----> 1 original.reduce(mean_squared_error, dim="time")

~/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py in reduce(self, func, dim, keep_attrs, keepdims, numeric_only, **kwargs)
   4915                         # the former is often more efficient
   4916                         reduce_dims = None  # type: ignore[assignment]
-> 4917                     variables[name] = var.reduce(
   4918                         func,
   4919                         dim=reduce_dims,

~/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/variable.py in reduce(self, func, dim, axis, keep_attrs, keepdims, **kwargs)
   1721             )
   1722             if axis is not None:
-> 1723                 data = func(self.data, axis=axis, **kwargs)
   1724             else:
   1725                 data = func(self.data, **kwargs)

~/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

TypeError: mean_squared_error() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Comment: Remember to, in case you found it, accept an answer! So people who will come after will have their life easier :)

Comment: Thanks @Saverio! I appreciate your comment and reply!. I should more clearly specify that RMSE was an example function. Ideally, I would like to be able to apply a number of the sklearn metrics from within xarray rather than using an external package or else doing xarray arithmetic as in @cyril's answer. I.e. using `.apply` or `.reduce`. I didn't like my own solution either!

Comment: Alright! Have you already tried to post this question into Xarray's GitHub Discussions? I am sure xarray's community is more active there. In case you post it there and found the answer, just re-post it here for the future.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package called [xskillscore](https://github.com/xarray-contrib/xskillscore/tree/stable), which has a method to calculate the MSE.

```py
pip install xskillscore

xskillscore.mse(original.obs, original.sim, 'time')
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would work :

```
np.sqrt(np.square(original["sim"] - original["obs"]).mean(dim="time"))
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution does not use the internal functions of xarray, but instead requires you to loop over all of your dimension `station_id`.

```py
from collections import defaultdict 

# calculate error metric
out = defaultdict(list)
for sid in original.station_id.values:
    data = original.sel(station_id=sid)
    orig_err = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(data["obs"], data["sim"]))
    out["original"].append(orig_err)
    out["station_id"].append(sid)

rmse = pd.DataFrame(out).set_index("station_id").to_xarray()
```

This gives you the solution but does not use the internal broadcasting features of `xarray` and so would struggle with larger datasets.